# How come I don't see any spaces between words on my website using Internet Explorer on Windows?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When I click inspect element, I see spaces between words. But when the html is rendered on the web page, I see no spaces between words, like "thebestvrexperience"

Comment: You need to post a [mcve] in your question so that we can see what you're talking about. And please don't just post a link to your website.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't do that. I'll close the question.

Comment: Debugging invisible code is real hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My font-family's spaces are not understood correctly by IE. Changing the font-family fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

We can't know for sure, if you not provide full details or examples, but I guess that can be an css issue.

Try to look to the [word-space](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_word-spacing.asp) property of you site.

> the word-spacing CSS property specifies the spacing behavior between tags and words.

Ex:

```css
#mozdiv1 {
  word-spacing: 15px;
}
    
#mozdiv2 {
  word-spacing: 5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="mozdiv1">Here are many words...</div>
<div id="mozdiv2">...and many more!</div>
```

Comment: Just tried, and it doesn't change anything.